# How can I create a sortable accordion with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-sortable

I found [ui sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable) and got it working nicely for simple lists and the like. My application already uses the [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and I want to sort the accordion elements.

The html looks nice:

```
<div ng:controller="controller">
    <accordion ui:sortable ng:model="list">
        <accordion-group ng:repeat="item in list" class="item">
            <accordion-heading>{{item}}</accordion-heading>
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
</div>
```

However, while this works with the accordion bits swapped for ul/li etc. it does not work for the accordion element. [Here is the non working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whippy/bwq82bvs/). The drag action just picks up the entire accordion.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going suggest using a handle in the sort options, but it doesn't seem to help.

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
    handle: '.handle'
}
```

Here's a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ydx3Lo?p=preview)

I'm gonna say the 2 just don't play well together.

You may have better luck with something like http://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/

Comment: Cool demo of angular-ui-tree. The items don't expand (other than for the subtree elements which is not something I need) - so it is not an accordion. I'll wait a bit in the hope of an accordion style solution. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I would probably use the sortable because its hard to recreate and just improvise an accordion because it is super simple. http://plnkr.co/edit/Ydx3Lo?p=preview

Comment: I followed the advice and improvised the accordion.

Answer (score 5):

I've came across this trouble. I've solved using a $decorator, which is very useful to edit third-party libraries without touching the core. The exactly code is:

```
yourModule.config(['$provide', function ($provide){
    $provide.decorator('accordionDirective', function($delegate) { 
        var directive = $delegate[0];
        directive.replace = true;
        return $delegate;
    });
}]);
```

What the code does is replace the template that the accordion directive is wrapping, so now the ng-repeat is a direct child of the ui-sortable directive, and it should work.

Also, as @Dylan says, I suggest to use a "handler" to prevent the accordion from opening when sorting.

Comment: This is interesting. I will look at it as a decent solution if I need to revisit the code.

Comment: No, I rewrote the accordion with my own directive and moved on. I will try your suggestion when I revisit the code or need to do the same thing again.

Comment: @AlexJ liked your solution. Created a [mock plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TGIeeEbbvJwpJ3WRqo2z?p=preview).

Comment: Hi @ThodorisGreasidis, thanks! It would be useful to show it ;)