# Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed while restore array from local storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, accordion, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm working with angular-ui bootstrap [accordion directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) and did it sortable with help [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520131/how-can-i-create-a-sortable-accordion-with-angularjs). Now I'm working on functions storing and restoring accordion state and got some problem with restoring this state. When I apply saved state from local storage, I'm getting an error:

> Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: group in groups, Duplicate key: string:"

My functions looks like :

```
      $scope.storeState = function () {
            localStorage.setItem("state", JSON.stringify($scope.groups))
        };
        $scope.restoreState = function () {
           var retrieve = localStorage.getItem("state");
            $scope.groups = retrieve
        };
```

It is simple functions for set and get item from local storage. I have tried to set `$scope.groups = []`, inside restore state function but it didn't help, also I have tried to use `track by $index`, `track by $id(group)` or `group in groups track by group.(some obj)` but it doesn't work or just breaks the whole app. So, could anybody help me to find what I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

my code and [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4j4SwmxpnE6WuxJm5r9t?p=preview)

```
    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.sortable'])
  .config(['$provide', function ($provide){
    $provide.decorator('accordionDirective', function($delegate) { 
        var directive = $delegate[0];
        directive.replace = true;
        return $delegate;
    });
  }])
  .controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.oneAtATime = false;
    $scope.isOpen = false;
    $scope.isClicked = false;

    $scope.sortableOptions = {
        handle: ' .handle',
        update: function(event, ui) {
                    $timeout(function(){
                        $scope.order = ui.item.index();
                    });
                }
    }

  $scope.groups = [
      {
        index: 0,
        title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 1',
        content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 1',
        isOpen: false

      },
      {
        index: 1,
        title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 2',
        content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 2',
        isOpen: false

      },
      {
        index: 2,
        title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 3',
        content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 3',
        isOpen: false
      }
    ];


  $scope.$watch('isOpen', function(newval, oldval){
    if(oldval !== newval) {
        $scope.state = newval ? 'opening' : 'closing';
       }
     })


  $scope.updateOpenStatus = function(obj){
    $scope.isOpen = $scope.groups.some(function(item){
      return item.isOpen;
    });
  }

  $scope.updateClickStatus = function(group){
    $scope.isClicked = true;
  }

  // functions store / restore state


            $scope.storeState = function () {
                localStorage.setItem("state", JSON.stringify($scope.groups))
            };
            $scope.restoreState = function () {
               var retrieve = localStorage.getItem("state");
               $scope.groups = []
               console.log(retrieve)
                $scope.groups = retrieve
            };



  });
```

html

```
  <h2>Accordion</h2>
<ul accordion close-others="oneAtATime" ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="groups">
  <li accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" is-open="group.isOpen" ng-click="updateOpenStatus(group)">
    <accordion-heading>
      <div class="handle btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></i></div>
      {{group.title}}
    </accordion-heading>
      <div ng-click="updateClickStatus(group)"> 
         {{group.content}}
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>


<hr>
<h4>Panel Order: {{order}}</h4><br>
<h4>Panel Header Open: {{isOpen}} </h4><br>
<h4>Panel Content Click: {{isClicked}}</h4><br>
<h4>Panel state : {{state}}</h4><br>
<h4><b>Result:</b>  <span ng-if ="isClicked && isOpen"> True</span></h4><br>


<!-- ******************** -->


<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="storeState()">store</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="restoreState()">restore</button>
```

Comment: It looks like you lack `JSON.parse` after calling `localStorage.getItem`. Local storage can only contain strings. You correctly use `JSON.stringify` to convert your object to a tree, but then you don't use `JSON.parse` to convert a string you get from localStorage back to an object.

Comment: @PawełChorążyk OMG, there is so stupid mistake, I appreciate your help